# what happen when we use assembly sections like .text or .data inside the functions?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I found some weird assembly code that used sections inside the functions what this method would do for us ?

[here is the image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKi41.png)

Comment: I'd except the assembler to join all the sections with the same name into a single section. So it's just as having a single `SECTION .text` at the top. Probably the author didn't understand the assembler directives.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code please.  Instead, copy your code as text into the question.

Comment: You never want to do that.  If you aren't sure the current section is `.text`, you should put your `foo:` label *after* switching to the section where you're putting the machine code.  The `global foo` can be anywhere; it's just a directive that modifies `foo` wherever its declared.